# Консольная игра ошибка на C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Всех поздравляю с наступающим!!! Учусь C# и вот решил написать консольную игру простенькую, подскажите пожалуйста что в моём коде не так то есть не компилиться она, а если и компилиться то не переходит по ветке свитча например ввожу координаты 0,0 нажимаю клавишу Enter и ничего не происходит вот мой код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace AppGame
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[,] text = new string[2, 2];
            do
            {
                text[0, 0] = "Привет Мир!!! Я делаю консольную Игру поддержите проект интеллектуально!";
                text[0, 1] = "Hello, World!!!";
                text[1, 0] = "В этой комнате лежит книга 20 000 лье под водой!";
                text[1, 1] = "Лежит ключ от двери из этого дома!";

                Console.WriteLine("Здесь четыре комнаты 1 на 1 при  раскладе 2 на 2 это стены");
                text[2, 2] = Convert.ToString(ConsoleKey.Enter);

                text[2, 2] = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (text[2, 2])
                {
                    case "0, 0":
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(text[0, 0]);
                            break;
                        }
                    case "0,1":
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(text[0, 1]);
                            break;
                        }
                    case "1,0":
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(text[1, 0]);
                            break;
                        }
                    case "1,1":
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(text[1, 1]);
                            break;
                        }
                    default:
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\nнет такой локации или команды");
                            break;
                        }
                    case "чисто":
                        {
                            Console.Clear();
                            break;
                        }

                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            } while (true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы знаете, в VisualStudio есть такая полезная штука - отладчик.

Comment: Igor я плохо понимаю отладчик на уровне начинающего C# программиста, если сказать вообще плохо понимаю его, подскажите в чём ошибка пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Индексы массивов в C# изменяются от нуля до длины массива минус один.

```
string[,] text = new string[2, 2]; // матрица строк 2х2
...
text[2, 2] = ...; // пытается присвоить значение третьему элементу в третьей строке матрицы, вылезает за границу массива
```

Comment: И что делать с третьим элементом в третьей строке матрицы

Comment: @Сергей Зачем Вам вообще матрица? Заведите пять строковых переменных.

Comment: Хорошо попробую